# C Include custom header file in Geany on Windows 10 compiling with gcc

Tags: c

I'm having an incredibally hard time finding answers to this for Windows. As if the majority of people use Linux...

Anyways, I need a custom CSV parsing library for C. I found one and downloaded the header file. I tried adding `#include <csvparser.h>` at the top of my c program but of course, it says file not found. I placed the downloaded file in the same directory as the program.

I think i need to be able to specify an absolute path in the include or place the file csvparser.h in the include directory, but I know how to do neither of these things. What is the default include directory in Windows? I use gcc as my compiler. How can i specify an absolute path in the include statement, on windows? i can find no answer to this.

Thanks!

EDIT

Thank you for the quick reply, I seem to have included the file correctly, but now I'mhaving problems using it.

I found the program at https://sourceforge.net/p/cccsvparser/wiki/Home/

I placed it in the source directory and tried using it, bbut when I try the usage example I'm getting an error. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "csvparser.h"


#define MAXCHAR 10000

int main() {
    
    // int i =  0;
    // file, delimiter, first_line_is_header?
    
    CsvParser *csvparser = CsvParser_new("../MagicProg/Files/MagicProg_csv_ikoria.csv", "|", 1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I try executing this, geany gives me the error:

C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Geoff\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsiwJPq.o:hello.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `CsvParser_new'

What am I doing wrong? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you're including something that's in your source directory you need to use a different style:

```
#include "csvparser.h"
```

The angle-brackets form is *exclusively* for things found in your include path, **not** in your source directory. That's reserved for things like OS and compiler headers, as well as system-installed libraries.

Comment: New problem? New question. Try and keep each focused on a single issue we can answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made the huge newb error of not including the src files along with the header file. I blame myself. thanks everyone for help